# Drill through reports in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts, report, ssrs-2008-r2

I am making a report that takes in date parameters to filter result and shows the result in a pie-chart. I want to create a drill-through (could be drill down or any other type) where if a user clicks on a part of a pie chart which is divided by Agent names (as shown in image) a second report should open that takes in the date parameter from the first report and the agents name from the area of the chart where the user clicks the pie chart.

I have managed to pass the date parameters but the latter part, passing the agents name is where I need help.

[image]

So If I click on lets say the grey area, the other report should open the records only for that Assigned To agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this can be done.

On the charts, **Series Properties**, you use the **Action** tab and **Go To Report**. Choose your drill through report and **Add** the parameters.

For your **Agent** parameter, you would use your

```
=Fields!AssignedTo.Value
```

as the parameter **Value**. This will pass the selected pie slice as the AssignedTo agent in the drill through report.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this possible clicking on the graph itself. I would suggest a work-around. I would create a table beside it with a list of all your "Assigned Tos." Add an Action to the new table that links to your Drill Through report, using AssignedTo.Value as one of the parameters that you pass to your second report.